# Push Notifications in iOS for Progressive Web Apps

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a Progressive Web App by using Javascript. I am unable to receive Push Notifications in iOS platform for my app, but at the same time i am receiving Notifications for Android and Web apps browsers. I read somewhere still no support for iOS notifications. Please help me if you guys have any info to achieve this.

Comment: You can't, end of story.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the leading browsers with the exception of Safari on iOS supports web push API. While Safari does support push notifications on Mac OS, there is no green signal for push notification iOS. Read full article [here](https://www.izooto.com/blog/ios-push-notifications-safari).

Push notification support for iOS Safari not added by Apple yet. So you need wait until support gets added. or you can think about alternatives like showing the notifications as alerts/pop ups/notification center in iOS PWA.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What do you mean by "showing the notifications as alters/pop ups/notification center in iOS PWA." ?

Comment: @DamienRomito - you can build a notification centre as a service. When ever user opens PWA and online, you and send call to notification centre service and fetch the notifications and show within the PWA itself.

Comment: @RajeshG could you extend this comment? I am trying to build an alternative for my PWA. If I could send a notification from a PWA in iOS, even if the web-app needs to be open, that would be okay, but I don't understand your proposal using just javascript or server side code.

Comment: @Jorge you need to build your own custom service for IOS based on your needs. This is what I will do, I will build URL which will return a JSON with notification details. I will not cache this URL in service worker. So, every time we open PWA from iPhone, this URL will be hit and fetch back JSON and using any JS library I will parse the JSON to add notifications to PWA. you need to be creative and implement your own solution. Hope this helps.