# Supporting Service Worker and Push Notifications for PWA on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, progressive-web-apps

We have been building a PWA for quite sometime now. We have completed 70% of our project and have hit a stumbling block: no push notification and service worker support for iOS! I wasn't even aware that a feature as common as these were not supported for iOS.

I have read a few posts on SO and some have suggested (with a warning of App Store rejecting the app) that a barebone cordova wrapper might solve these issues. I am quite worried at this point and would like a definitive answer as to how much effort do we need to wrap our PWA with Cordova and allow Push Notifications and Service Worker. Rewriting the app is simply not an option for us at this point and it would be great if someone can provide a few guidelines as to possible avenues we can investigate.

Also, FYI, WebSocket based solutions would also be extremely difficult for us.

For reference, these are the 3 posts I have read so far:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59469783/push-notifications-in-ios-for-progressive-web-apps)
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361646/how-to-send-push-notification-to-ios-webapp-pwa)
[Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692775/ios-12-web-push-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know much about Cordova but push notification is still not available on iOS**

Even the Add to home screen pop will not show automatically we need to do manually only.

Apple added initial support for some PWA characteristics in iOS 11.3 in march 2018.

JAN2019 UPDATE: It seems like Apple is moving forward! Beta1 of iOS 12.2 has improved PWA support. Still no push notifications though:
https://medium.com/dev-channel/progressive-web-app-progress-in-ios-12-2-beta-1-build-16e5181f-a18cd05ca361

And you can check using the following link what are the features supported in the device.
https://tomayac.github.io/pwa-feature-detector/

Comment: This sheds some light into the issue but, it still doesn't explain how to support iOS version below 12.2. We have been experimenting with Cordova wrappers and can have a definite answer in a few days.

Comment: @AbrarHossain mee to faced the same problem in our project but the fact is there is no support in PWA. we finally told the client same. you could check if some other way to send notification using Cordova.

Comment: @AbrarHossain in recent we got an idea to implement push notification on ios as basically, you have a Cordova application so definitely once you registered with iOS app store while installing the application a unique id will generate for each user you can send notification